# How to display X images of the same size in the browser responsively

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I have a list, in my list I have XX images (for my example we can say 50), I would like these images to be the same size (H/W) and take all the space of screenview.

I tried with the `display: flex; flex: wrap;` and the item with `flex: 1;` but they line up, it doesn't wrap.

I also tried to assign the height and width of each item with a `calc(100vw / (100vh / 50));` but I don't know at all how to set the count of images there will be depending on the size of the screen.

I thought of a JS solution to give the sizes to each item but I don't know how to calculate the item.
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofnkLr61/1/)

If you have any suggestion, I'll take it.

Expected result:
[image]

Comment: blocks should be folded according to the `flex-wrap: wrap` principle?

Comment: not necessarily, I would just like the items to take the full window size with the same H/W, I thought the `flex-wrap` would do this easily but it looks like I need to give it a size that I don't know how to calculate.

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/vwzh5pG

Comment: yes, if we add another item and everything realigns properly and there is no need to scroll, that's exactly what I want

Comment: now I will give two solutions (two snippets). The second solution will be the space between the blocks.

Comment: I have given a solution. Was it necessary?

Comment: arg, I know this solution, my particularity is that I don't want us to scroll in the page, I want all the items to be displayed without needing to scroll

Comment: ah, excuse me, not completely other than your question. But you can try something like height: calc (100% / 4); for block

Comment: Why don't you want to do it with a grid?

Comment: we can do with a grid, as long as I manage to fit the items into the window without having to scroll, it's perfect, i'm trying `display: grid` with `auto-fit` it's getting closer but I haven't found it yet

Comment: It's much easier to do this with a grid.

Comment: I believe you, I still haven't found xD

Comment: it's my try for the moment [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zh9wbre6/)

Comment: Hi. Yesterday I fell asleep as it was night. I made a decision for you the way you wanted. If still relevant ...

Comment: + Made a second solution with a space between blocks

Answer (score 0):

you can use these:-
display: flex property :-
[image: jsfiddlearnab]

https://jsfiddle.net/hn3csx0g/

```css
.imageGallery{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.imageParent{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.imageParent > img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageGallery">


<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>


<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>


<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>



<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>



<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>


<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>


<div class="imageParent">
<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg"/>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: hello, I need the size of the image to be automated, so that it takes all the space necessary for it to be in fullscreen, that there are 2/3/10/20/50

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, the width of the blocks is calculated for the width of the screen, respectively, these blocks are stretched to fill the screen with this rule:

```
width: calc(100% / 5);
height: calc(100% / 4);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item{
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

second solution:

In this solution, there is a distance between blocks. The calculation of the width of the blocks relative to the distance between the blocks themselves is calculated as follows:

```
width: calc((100% / 5) - (80px / 5));
height: calc((100% / 4) - (60px / 4));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item{
  width: calc((100% / 5) - (80px / 5));
  height: calc((100% / 4) - (60px / 4));
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```